# How to mock CreateBatchWrite object in Xunit

Tags: c#, moq, xunit, aws-sdk-net

I’m writing a unit test in c# and I need to mock the response of  CreateBatchWrite using Moq but not able to instantiate an object of the BatchWrite object. I’m doing this:
`_dbContext.Setup(m => m.CreateBatchWrite<type>(It.IsAny<DynamoDBOperationConfig>())) .Returns(Mock.Of<BatchWrite<type>>());`

I'm currently trying this but getting error :
`System.NotSupportedException: Parent does not have a default constructor. The default constructor must be explicitly defined.` 
Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

As BatchWrite has no default constructor, you have to wrap it in another class that *you* can control, i.e., one with a default constructor...

For example:

```
public class BatchWriteWrapper<T>
{
    private readonly BatchWrite<T> _batchWrite;

    public BatchWriteWrapper()
    { }

    public BatchWriteWrapper(BatchWrite<T> batchWrite)
    {
        _batchWrite = batchWrite;
    }

    public void MethodFromBatchWrite()
    {
        _batchWrite.MethodFromBatchWrite();
    }
    
    // etc.
}
```

In your code you can now instantiate your wrapper class with BatchWrite instance and test on the wrapper instance.

Your `_dbContext` can be set up as follows:

```
_dbContext.Setup(m => m.CreateBatchWrite<type>(It.IsAny<DynamoDBOperationConfig>()))
.Returns(Mock.Of<BatchWriteWrapper<type>>());
```

And in your code, you wrap any `BatchWrite` instance you get, and use the wrapper instead:

```
var batchWrite = new BatchWriteWrapper(_dbContext.CreateBatchWrite<type>(...));
```

---

If you want to take it a step further, you can also wrap the type of your `_dbContext` so that it returns wrapped instances instead of its own (non-mockable) instances.

Comment: Can you explain with an example?

Comment: This doesn't help as it is the BatchWrite<T> object that cannot be created.